# How to put a black color with opacity on an image in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I'd like to know how can I put a black rectangle with opacity on the top of an image in Swift 3. For example:

[image]
[image]

Comment: This is easy. What's the hard part for you? Show what you have tried and explain what happened.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can create a `UIView` that is black with an opacity and make it the same size of your `UIImageView` and add it as subview. Try something like:

```
let tintView = UIView()
tintView.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0, alpha: 0.5) //change to your liking
tintView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: imageView.frame.width, height: imageView.frame.height)

imageView.addSubview(tintView)
```

**imageView** = Your UIImageView

Comment: This assumes there is an image view. The question isn't clear at all. They may be asking how to modify a `UIImage`.

Answer (score 2):

```
func drawRectOn(image: UIImage) -> UIImage {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(image.size)
    image.draw(at: CGPoint.zero)
    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

    // set fill gray and alpha
    context!.setFillColor(gray: 0, alpha: 0.5)
    context!.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
    context!.fill(CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: image.size.width, height: image.size.height))
    context!.strokePath()
    let resultImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()

    // end the graphics context
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return resultImage!

}
```

Comment: No need to call move to (you already have the fill origin set). You can use `defer {UIGraphicsEndImageContext()}` to postpone ending image context to make it happen after returning the UIImage. Also to make it shorter `image.draw(at: .zero)`, `context!.move(to: .zero)` and `currentContext!.fill(CGRect(origin: .zero, size: image.size))`. No need to stroke it also

Comment: Agree. It was artifacts :)